# How to obtain Disk Image of OS X Beta?

Tags: macos, developer-program, beta-seed-program

We use JAMF's Casper Suite to deploy our Macs, and would like to be able to push out the OS X Developer Beta to some machines to do some testing before the public release.

I have downloaded the Beta from the Developer site however it gives me a 'OS X El Capitan Developer Beta Access Utility' when I need a DMG.

After running the file, it takes me to the updates page of the App Store and allows me to download the update.

Is it possible to get the full disk image from somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid a DMG isn't downloadable.

I think it may be possible by the following steps: (haven't tried it myself yet)

1. Create a new disk image through Disk Utility at a size large enough to fit a system (about 40G should be good, you can shrink it later)
2. Mount the disk image
3. Using the installer downloaded from the App Store, install El Capitan Beta on the mounted disk image
4. Eject and export the disk image.